# How to create two database records at the same time, that do not have sequential Ids

Tags: c#, java, mysql, sql, sql-server

We currently have a website with user login.

We have a user table with userId.

We now want users to have a duplicate profile, that is entirely seperate from their main profile. This needs to be a secret profile.

Now we could just add two records into the db, but the id's would be sequential (until we hit a high hit rate of signups) so a user could workout that a userId would be related to one ID higher.

I realise this is not an ideal solution, but it is a late change to a big software project so we are trying to be as pragmatic as possible, while requiring as little code change as possible.

Options:

1. Turn off auto increment Ids, and build our own keyGeneration table. Start one table at 0, and start the secret one at 1000000000. We then can then turn off auto incrementing ID's in the user table, and use these keys.

The problem is, does having keys running, 1,1000000000,2,1000000001,3,1000000002 cause a massive indexing problem? Would we have to force index rebuilds all the time?

1. We key a seperate table just for the 2nd profile id's, again starting at 10000000000. We then modify all our code to check for id's > 999999999 and flip the logic on the server side so the lookups work correctly.

Means doing that check everywhere a user ID is passed into the site, from the front end.

As we don't do that too much, (we obviously mainly grab userId of logged in user securely, it might not be that bad.

Anyway, just wondering if anyone has any thoughts on this?

///////Edit

To put this into further context, imagine on stackoverflow or facebook, you have 2 profiles that you can control, that have no link between them. Like the way multiple users on Facebook can all act as a Page account, yet there is no link back from that account to the real user profile.

Essentially to not break referential integrity or re write too much code, I really want to pass an ID (int) back down to the front end for these account. Then the whole system just keeps ticking over as it has done.

Guid could be cool! But it would have a performance overhead (NOT THAT I CARE ABOUT THAT REALLY ;) but it would also mean writing a lot of code to handle Guids being what is passed to the front end (not that we rely on front end variables being right) but that is why I suggest the high int solution above. As we still have ASP.NET Membership lurking in the background I almost thought that could be good but A) we plan to remove that one day (or migrate to simple membership) b) we use sequential Guid generation in our user table for performance (sorry again to talk about optimization, before it's needed)

Comment: Add `isSecret` field to a table and don't allow users to see hidden profiles.

Comment: You could create a new User2 table without auto inc id.  Then from User1 use an insert trigger to create an initial duplication record.

Comment: what is the reason that knowing the ids is dangerous? if the security depends on just *not knowing the ids*, that sounds ... incomplete. Understanding the context is important for security related questions.

Comment: agree with @MarcGravell - you should still theoretically have a link between the two user accounts somehow in data or code - the issue here is not the value of the key but the overall security model.  the only reason i see to split this to another table is maybe some table level security - but this could also be done all in one table with a flag as Minras suggests...

Comment: To put this into further context, imagine on stackoverflow or facebook, you have 2 profiles that you can control, that have no link between them. Like the way multiple users on Facebook can all act as a Page account, yet there is no link back from that account to the real user profile. If there was a link between ints or even a chance of that, then we have a security risk (any normal font end user should not be able to workout which account links to which account) OK so not using int's is a good idea, but that means a lot of code change.

Comment: We already have fields like isSecret for internal use. But at the moment, if we go the simplest route, you will know that each user id is followed by the id of the secret profile? Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guid, randon numbers by a web service. Plenty of solutions. I would rather go with a GUID.

THAT SAID: This is a business key, i would still use an autoincrement style technical key for referential integrity.

Comment: +1 I second this: have "public" and "private" IDs. Public = GUID and is given to the end user etc. Private = sequential for performance (as discussed many times before). Server side, you resolve public to private once and use this from then on

Comment: Great idea, although if we had to use guid, that would mean passing guids to the front end for these profiles. And then changing our input mechanism for these posts to guid. Hey maybe that isn't a bad idea at all! Could we leave public profiles as ints, and private ones as guids? That feels cleaner to me?

Comment: I would go with ints internally - you want th database side keys to be SMALL for join performance, the rest is a business decision. heck, you could use a mersenne twister service to generate a unique but not obviously sequential sequence of numbers from a central place.

Comment: The more I think about it, I think we have to accept there will be a translation from public number to private, and that has to end up on the front end. We then have to cope with accepting that back as an input. The good thing is, for the user who is currently logged in, we don't need to trust their front end id, as that is done via their userId anyway. It's only other users who need to look at the private profile who need something like a guid.

Comment: Our system we already had in place was basically fine. I just wanted to check what we were doing was sane.